# A way of saying that "the advantages of a strategy go in two different directions"?

Tags: expressions, vocabulary, idiom-requests, phrase-requests

For example, a Government decides to construct a much-needed bridge. This helps the Government get into good books of people and secure their vote. Secondly, this also gives them some economic benefit.

So there are two different advantages. The benefits for the government are in two different directions.

> The **advantages** of this strategy **go in two directions.**

This one is a very crude and unsophisticated way of saying it.

I am particularly looking for a replacement of the word "*advantage*" and "*go in two directions*".

So what would be a nicer way of saying this?

Comment: It can be hard to find a win-win in looking for such phrases.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I feel like *advantages* sounds fine. You mentioned *benefits*, which also works. So my only contribution is *twofold*:

> The  advantages of this strategy are **twofold**.

where

> [twofold](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/twofold)
>   : having two parts

Answer (score 4):

Kill two birds with one stone.

[**From TFD**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/kill+two+birds+with+one+stone):

> Achieve two ends with a single effort.

Answer (score 1):

**bilateral**

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bilateral)

> 1. pertaining to, involving, or affecting two or both sides, factions, parties, or the like:
>
> *a bilateral agreement; bilateral sponsorship.*

---

**double-edged**

[Collins dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/double-edged)

> 1. acting in two ways; having a dual effect ⇒ *a double-edged law*

Comment: double-edged came to mind first, but it sometimes implies positive and *negative* effects

Answer (score 1):

Orthogonal advantages?

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/orthogonal) says:

> adjective
>   1. Mathematics. Also, orthographic. pertaining to or involving right angles or perpendiculars:
>   an orthogonal projection.

They're not opposing but in two different directions.

Comment: Arguably the core of a good answer -- but where are definition, source, link?  At 2K rep, you know the mores here!

Comment: @ab2 at 8k rep you know how to preach